# How to run rake task but running process continue in many days with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake-task

In my rails project, I am going to update **longitude** and **latitude** field of **location** table, but I want to update 100 records each day until end of records. Who can give me a suggest?

Comment: How about you update 100 records each day until end of records? That should achieve your goal.

Comment: I want to run rake task to update all records but each day only update 100 records until the end.

Comment: Sounds great! God for it!

Comment: can you please provide the code you wrote and explain the issue you have? It's difficult (as jvillain is trying to suggest you) to solve your problem if we don't know what you tried and why is not working.

Comment: @coorasse Thank you for comment, now I can solve it with delayed_job: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#rails-42

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a `rake` task which will take 100 records (which are not updated yet) and update it.
Now you can schedule this task to run everyday.

For example if you are using `Heroku` you can use [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler)  to schedul you rake task. **And its free**

Comment: Thank you, I can use delayed_job to solve it instead :))